# glassfish server serving xml instead of adf webpage

Tags: oracle, glassfish, glassfish-3, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am running a glassfish 3.1.2 server with ADF essential libraries added to it. The server runs fines, deploys all my applications without any errors but serves up xml code instead of web pages. I have to say that the rich client faces demo runs fine. So there must be something wrong with my applications' EARs. I have tried taking the RCF demo's libraries to manually package them in my war inside my ear without success.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be wrong?

I have a unmodified straightforward glassfish 3.1.2 downloaded from Oracle and configured as per Oracle's instructions to run ADF applications (hence the demo works), adf essentials downloaded from Oracle as well. Versions of adf essentials match the version of jdeveloper (12.1.2) Here is the document declaration from the outputed xml code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<f:view xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich"
    xmlns:dvt="http://xmlns.oracle.com/dss/adf/faces">
```

I tried adding different libraries to the application deployment settings to no avail. I have tried none-to-all of them without success. (this took a long time to try)

Do you have any suggestions for me to check in order for the glassfish server to serve webpages instead of  brute xml?

Best regards

Marc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled across the answer:

I needed to add /faces in front of the webpage. Thus the url looks like

```
http://is-marca-v:9090/HRSystem-ViewController-context-root/faces/DeptEmpPage.jsf
```

and not

```
http://is-marca-v:9090/HRSystem-ViewController-context-root/DeptEmpPage.jsf
```

Have a nice day to you all.